# Group Policy Editor is not showing in Administration tool's list

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, windows

I just installed the Windows 2003 server administration pack SP1 but I need to set a new GPO but it's not listed in All Programs - Administrative Tools

When I open MMC, I add a snap-in and the Group Policy is available but it's prompting me to add a server... So I add it but I don't have access to it (as per the error message) but it was working last week with my Windows XP... ??????

Is anybody knows how to fix this and how I can use GP Editor in my MMC?

I'm on Windows 7

Comment: Which edition of Windows 7 (Starter, Home Premium, Professional or Ultimate) do you have?

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate. The big one!

Comment: This has been moved from SU... I don't have any issue with servers! Just with my local computer... that I just fixed by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this problem, it's quite simple...

First of all, on Windows 7, the Windows 2003 SP1 administration tool doesn't work well so you need to install this patch first:

> x86fre_GRMRSAT_MSU

Then, you install the AdminKit SP1 for Windows 2003.

The trick is here:

You need to go there:

Control panel - Programs - Turn Windows features on or off - Remote Server administation tools (I checked all of them and I got my issue fixed!)

Answer (score 1):

First I would install the [Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7D2F6AD7-656B-4313-A005-4E344E43997D&displaylang=en). Then add the feature.  You will then have the GPMC.

Answer (score -1):

The GPO editor isn't installed as a tool on its own, but can only be added to an MMC as a snap in, as you've done.

You can create/edit GPOs separately by using the Active Directory Users and Computers tool, browsing to the OU/Domain to which you wish to add it, and add/edit the GPO from its properties (assuming you have permission to do so).

Make sure you're logged in as an Active Directory Administrator (or other appropriately privileged account). Only admins or suitably delegated accounts have permissions to add GPOs to the domain or to OUs within the domain.

You could use Run As... to run that MMC console as admin, if you're not already logged into the domain with that account.

Comment: GPMC can be run without being opened by MMC